# Pandas - plotting multiple histograms

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with a hundred different subsets of data, each consisting of a feww records. I want to visualize the distribution of each subset using a histogram ie, I want to plot 100 histogram. How do I do this?

I tried this, but all the histograms are going into the same chart.

```
for i in range(100):
    desc_raw[desc_raw['ID'].isin(id_nodes[i])]['SubInd'].hist()
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: do you need `desc_raw.groupby('ID')['SubInd'].plot.hist()` ?

Comment: That errored out